# Boost Asio, io_service handles only one socket per core

Tags: sockets, concurrency, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am writing a server application using Boost Asio:

1. Server: Running io_service.run() from pool of threads (one thread per core), accepting connections & reading data from sockets is done asynchronously.
2. Client: Each client connects and sends a heavy file (~500MB) to the server.

Issue: All Clients are connected to the server (number of clients > number of server cores); io_service handles only one connection/socket per thread while data from other sockets are not processed until one of the processed connections completes.

I would expect that data from all connected sockets gets processed by the io_service thread pool at a same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the expected behavior? Your `io_service` can only invoke `n` handlers if you have `n` threads invoking `io_service::run()`. If the number of outstanding asynchronous operations is greater than `n`, their handlers will wait in the `io_service` queue until a thread is free to invoke them.

Comment: I would expect that data from all connected clients is processed (at a lower rate) by the thread pool and not to simply block all other clients waiting for one thread to become free. That would mean that one connection occupies one thread exclusively during the whole data transfer even if I read data from sockets asynchronous (This is actually what I am experiencing). Did I get something wrong ?

Comment: @Aldin how have you determined that one connection occupies a single thread invoking `io_service::run()`?

Comment: I added a log message to my connection::handle_read() function (server side), which prints the port number of the connection remote endpoint, and I get only reads for the first two connections (io_service thread pool = 2) while other connections are blocked (no log messages) until one of the first two connections completes which can take some time since large files are being transferred.

Comment: @Aldin are you using the `async_read` composed operation, or `async_read_some`?

Comment: @Aldin you should probably edit your question and add some code showing how you invoke `async_read_some`, it's most likely related to the behavior you experience.

Comment: It seems that the issue is related how I am sending files on the client side. I am currently using random_access_handle and the transmit_file function (from Boos::Asio examples) to transmit files.

Comment: If I send only random data from clients then I receive data (log messages) at a "same" time for all active connections on the server side. I don't know why this happens, maybe because Server and clients are running on the same machine, but it definitely has something to do with the TransmitFile overlapped I/O API operation.

Comment: I will try to test with clients on different hosts, and see how it works. Sam, thanks for taking the time to comment on my issue. Cheers.

Comment: Just for record: "On Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, and Windows NT Workstation 3.51 and later only TWO outstanding TransmitFile requests are handled simultaneously; the third request will wait until one of the previous requests is completed."